# Callback on React Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

## Hey There

I have a question, i come from Swift an Java enviroment and do not get the syntax from this Problem. I want to pass a function as parameter of my function. But there is still an error. Can someone see the problem?

```
ServiceClass.load({(firstValue, secondValue)=>
    this.setState({
        firstValue: firstValue,
        secondValue: secondValue,
    });
    })
```

with my class

```
    export default class ServiceClass extends Component {
    static load(callback){
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/values')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJSON) => {
                callback(responseJSON.firstValue, responseJSON.secondValue)

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("loading error: ", error);
            });
    }
}
```

### Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extraneous curly brace in your `load` method. Or: the one you've added is in the wrong place. Anyway, here's how it should look:

```
ServiceClass.load((firstValue, secondValue) => {
  ...
});
```

Comment: @auryn31, and it's the answer that let me hit 21K in reputation, so thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 1):

You messed the order of the opening curly braces, it should be opened after the arrow:

```
ServiceClass.load((firstValue, secondValue) => {
    this.setState({
        firstValue: firstValue,
        secondValue: secondValue,
    });
})
```